# Changing the hostname in libcurl in C

Tags: c, linux, curl, smtp, hostname

I'm trying to play with libcurl SMTP and everything works fine with this example: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

/* This is a simple example showing how to send mail using libcurl's SMTP
 * capabilities. For an exmaple of using the multi interface please see
 * smtp-multi.c.
 *
 * Note that this example requires libcurl 7.20.0 or above.
 */ 

#define FROM    "<sender@example.org>"
#define TO      "<addressee@example.net>"
#define CC      "<info@example.org>"

static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " TO "\r\n",
  "From: " FROM "(Example User)\r\n",
  "Cc: " CC "(Another example User)\r\n",
  "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
  "Subject: SMTP example message\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */ 
  "The body of the message starts here.\r\n",
  "\r\n",
  "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
  "Check RFC5322.\r\n",
  NULL
};

struct upload_status {
  int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
  const char *data;

  if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
    return 0;
  }

  data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

  if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->lines_read++;

    return len;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
  struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
  struct upload_status upload_ctx;

  upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* This is the URL for your mailserver */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://mail.example.com");

    /* Note that this option isn't strictly required, omitting it will result in
     * libcurl sending the MAIL FROM command with empty sender data. All
     * autoresponses should have an empty reverse-path, and should be directed
     * to the address in the reverse-path which triggered them. Otherwise, they
     * could cause an endless loop. See RFC 5321 Section 4.5.5 for more details.
     */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);

    /* Add two recipients, in this particular case they correspond to the
     * To: and Cc: addressees in the header, but they could be any kind of
     * recipient. */ 
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, CC);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

    /* We're using a callback function to specify the payload (the headers and
     * body of the message). You could just use the CURLOPT_READDATA option to
     * specify a FILE pointer to read from. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* Send the message */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Free the list of recipients */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

    /* curl won't send the QUIT command until you call cleanup, so you should be
     * able to re-use this connection for additional messages (setting
     * CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM and CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT as required, and calling
     * curl_easy_perform() again. It may not be a good idea to keep the
     * connection open for a very long time though (more than a few minutes may
     * result in the server timing out the connection), and you do want to clean
     * up in the end.
     */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return (int)res;
}
```

The email which I send looks like this:

```
Return-Path: ...
Received: from Hostname (ip)
...
Date:...
Subject:...
...
```

But how could I change my own hostname from libcurl. Is it possible to send it in the header or something like this? Or I only could change it by adding the lines in /etc/hostname file?

Comment: The "*`Received:`*" line is added by the MTA after it received the mail (after it had been send). As you use curl to send the mail, which obviously is done before it is being received (by the MTA) there is no way to modify it via curl directly.